# PostgreSQL can't authenticate from localhost, but only from remote

Tags: centos, postgresql

I have a server with postgreSQL running. A few days ago I set it up so that I can access the database remotely from my home PC and that worked (based on this guide: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html). Now I noticed that for whatever reason, I can not access the database via localhost or 127.0.0.1.

`psql mydatabase` works without any problem. `psql -h myDomain.net mydatabase` also works. `psql -h localhost mydatabase` tells me

`psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "smaug"`

I tried reverting the changes that I made earlier to get remote access to the DB to no avail.

What could be the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I found out the problem. Going to the file `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf`, looking for the line

`host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident`

and replacing `ident` with `trust` apparently fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `host    all   all   127.0.0.1/32    md5` to your `pg_hba.conf` and reload PostgreSQL service then.